# angular-loading-overlay doesn't show anything

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, overlay

I have an AngularJS frontent app, where I am using `angular-loading-overlay` library. The problem is that it doesn't show me my spinner.

I have a template with an assigned controller:

```
<div ng-controller="FooCtrl" data-ng-init="initFoo()">
    <div class="bs-loading-container" bs-loading-overlay="FOO" bs-loading-overlay-template-url="/static/spinner.html">
            ... here some ng-repeat, data for it is loading inside initFoo(); 
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller itself:

```
app.controller("FooCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', 'bsLoadingOverlayService',
    function ($scope, $http, bsLoadingOverlayService) {
        $scope.initFoo = function () {
            bsLoadingOverlayService.start({referenceId: 'FOO'});
            $http.get("/model").then(function (response) {
                    // some long-loading data 
            });
            bsLoadingOverlayService.stop({referenceId: 'FOO'});
        };
}]);
```

CSS fragment:

```
.bs-loading-container {
    position: relative; 
}
```

`spinner.html` itself is some div with text inside (I have simplified it for testing purposes):

```
<div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);">
    <h1>Please, wait...</h1>
</div>
```

There is no errors in console. The method `initFoo()` works fine, it loads a data and the data is drawn in the page after it is loaded fine. But during loading no spinner appears.

Furthermore, if I deliberately change  `bs-loading-overlay-template-url` to improper path, then I receive errors in console. That means, I guess, that library `angular-loading-overlay` itself was loaded well.

I know that it is always very specific, but may be any ideas what could I miss and what should I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are showing the overlay, and hiding it instantly

$http.get is a asynchronous. so you should hide the overlay inside the handler methods. Try this:

```
    $scope.initFoo = function () {
        bsLoadingOverlayService.start({referenceId: 'FOO'});
        $http.get("/model").then(function (response) {
                // some long-loading data 
                bsLoadingOverlayService.stop({referenceId: 'FOO'});
        });

    };
```